# Validating A Model On Pre-Test Post-Test Design

Tags: spss, structural-equation-modeling, intervention-analysis

I am phd candidate at primary education department. My aim is to validate a model but i have not find a exact answer yet.

I have 2 groups. (Actually 4 but only 2 of them are going to use to validate model) Those 2 groups had been tested both in pre and post.

Model is something like this. [image] I have tools to measure all dependent variables.

Is there any possiblity to validate this model in pre-post design? SEM may be one tool but i could not find an exact answer is it possible or not especially in pre post test design. Any regression analysis could help me?

P.S: My dataset is about 55 children (30 in 1 group, 25 in other group)

Comment: You need to explain why a pre-post design answers your question.  Due to dropouts, secular trends, and regression to the mean such a design seldom answers the question of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (a) you will use the new learning method on one of two classes of size $n=25$
with students assigned to the two classes at random (b) at the beginning and end of the term you give equivalent tests with normally distributed scores to students in both classes. Then you could find improvement scores for the 25 students in each class (post-score minus pre-score), and finally you could
compare improvement scores in the treatment class with the scores in the control class, using a procedure for two independent samples.

If the improvement scores are normally distributed with approximately the same standard deviation $\sigma,$ a two-sample t test could be used to test whether the treatment made a difference $\Delta = \frac 2 3 \sigma$ (in either direction). For a test at level $\alpha = 5\%,$ the probability of finding a true difference of size $\Delta$ (or larger) is about $90\%.$ This probability is called the power of the test.

Here is Minitab output for the situation described above. [You can change `assumed standard deviation` $\sigma$ and `Difference` $\Delta$ as long as the ratio $\Delta/\sigma = 2/3$ is held constant; this computation uses the 'non-central t distribution'.] In case you need a different ratio, other statistical software and online power calculators will perform similar computations.

```
Power and Sample Size 

1-Sample t Test

Testing mean = null (versus ≠ null)
Calculating power for mean = null + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 3


            Sample
Difference    Size     Power
         2      25  0.892017
```

[image]

*Notes and Clarifications:*

(1) The standard deviation $\sigma$ is for the test given to individual students, not the 'standard error' of an estimate. (The program computes the standard error.)

(2) Roughly speaking, the effective sample size in such a case is the size of the smaller class; the most efficient design is to have equal numbers of students in the two classes.

(3) If students were assigned to classes non-randomly, according to some criterion that might have an effect on ability to learn, then that effect can not be distinguished from the effect of the treatment.

(4) The computation is for a 'pooled' two-sample t test, which assumes equal variances for improvement score in both classes; if there is any doubt about this, you should use a Welch ('separate variances') two-sample t test instead (with some loss of power). If there is substantial doubt whether test scores are normally distributed, could use two-sample Wilcoxon tests to see if improvement scores differ between classes (again with some loss of power).

(5) It is possible to use a two-factor ANOVA to analyze such data, but under the assumptions mentioned above, the two-sample t test is equivalent to testing for significance of the 'Treatment' effect in the two-factor ANOVA. [If desired, you could do two separate 'paired t tests' (one for each class) to see whether there has been significant improvement in each class, taken separately.]